# How to update a Bokeh plot multiple times?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to iteratively add lines to a plot and change the color of previously plotted lines. For example to highlight only the most recent one. However, the following fails to update all colors apart from the very first line:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.io import push_notebook

fig=figure()
h=show(fig, notebook_handle=True)

ps=[fig.line([1,2],[i,i], color="black") for i in range(3)]

for p in ps:
    p.glyph.line_color="red"
    push_notebook(h)
```

It would only work if I do a single `push_notebook()`, however I would like to use multiple updates as my calculation is running.

How could I make this work?

EDIT:
The actual usage is maybe closer to this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.io import push_notebook

output_notebook()

fig=figure()
h=show(fig, notebook_handle=True)  # start plot and "slow" computation to watch

ps=[]

for i in range(3):
    p=fig.line([1,2],[i,i], line_width=2, color="red")  # new line in red
    if ps:
        ps[-1].glyph.line_color="black"   # old lines in black -> this is not happening
    ps.append(p)
    push_notebook(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `show` after everything is added:

```
fig=figure()

ps=[fig.line([1,2],[i,i], line_width=2, color="black") for i in range(3)]

# call show after lines are already added to figure
h=show(fig, notebook_handle=True)

for p in ps:
    p.glyph.line_color="red"
    push_notebook(h)
```

It's possible this could be considered a bug, I'm not sure. But that is the current behavior to contend with, in any case:

[image]

If you want something that does not have the limitations of `push_notebook`, you could consider [embedding a real Bokeh app in the notebook](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb)

Comment: Hmm, that defeats the purpose of lines being added after the first show. Maybe I adjust my example. Basically, I'd like some lines to already be shown when my calculation starts. As soon as another line is available, it should plot the new line in a special color and color all previous lines in a "neutral" color. And then repeat, while always showing the current state.

Comment: As I said, you can embed a real Bokeh app if you need to avoid limitations in `push_notebook`.